# How to disable a Neos backend menu entry with a condition

Tags: neoscms

I would like to disable a neos backend menu entry via config. More precisely, I installed flownative/neos-pixxio and only want to show the backend menu entry if configured (the same neos package that depends on pixxio is used on multiple websites, but not all should be able to see it).

I tried disabling the menu via the yaml setting:

```
    Neos:
      Neos:
        modules:
          management:
            submodules:
              flownativePixxio: ~
```

but that does not remove it, instead it just removes the label of the menu entry, leaving the menu entry blank, but clickable:

[image: Neos Backend Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Neos:
  Neos:
    modules:
      management:
        submodules:
          flownativePixxio:
            enabled: false
```

Comment: Works like a charm! How could I have found out myself? The documentation I found does not talk about this setting: https://docs.neos.io/cms/manual/extending-neos-with-php-flow/custom-backend-modules

Or was I just blind again? :D

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `hideInMenu`

```yaml
Neos:
  Neos:
    modules:
      management:
        submodules:
          flownativePixxio:
            hideInMenu: true
```

Comment: Thanks, that also works! I accepted Bastians answer, because he was faster :D Can only accept one, as it seems